# Comparing array with array of hashes and outputing new array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of subscription instances `@subscription_valids` and an array of subscribed player that look like that :

```
array_subscribed_players = [{"name0" => "link1"}, {"name1"=>"link2"}, {"name2"=>"link3"}....]
```

What I need to do is : for each subscription in `@subscription_valids` :

```
@subscription_valids.each do |subscription|
```

I need to check if `subscription.user.full_name` or if `subscription.user.full_name_inversed` matches a key in one of the hashes of `array_subscribed_player` (in the exemple "name0", "name1" or "name2").

If it matches then I should store the relevant  `subscription` as key in a hash in a new array and extract the relevant link as value of this hash. My final outpout should be an array that looks like this :

```
[{subscription1 => "link1"}, {subscription2 => "link2}, ...]
```

else if the  `subscription.user.full_name` doesnt match i'll just store the subscription in a failure array.

How can I achieve this result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
valid = array_subscribed_players.select{|x| @subscription_valids.map(&:name).include?(x.keys.first)}
```

[**Demo**](https://repl.it/BPzN)

If you need to store both valid and invalid values somewhere:

```
valid, invalid = array_subscribed_players.partition{|x| @subscription_valids.map(&:name).include?(x.keys.first)}
```

Comment: partition is the way to go here but the splat(`*`) is not needed. `a,b = [1,2]` will be `a #=> 1; b#=>2` as this is how parallel assignment works. since partition will always have a maximum of 2 nested arrays it would be a sufficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html

> A user-defined class may be used as a hash key if the hash and eql?
>   methods are overridden to provide meaningful behavior. By default,
>   separate instances refer to separate hash keys.

so I think you should override your .eql? method in @subscription_valids to something meaningful (like a unique string)

I can't think for a Array method so you can go like:

[demo](https://repl.it/BPzc/1)

```
results = []
failures = []
@subscription_valids.each do |subscription|
    array_subscribed_players.each do |player| 
        if player.keys.first == subscription.user.full_name || player.keys.first == subscription.user.full_name_inversed   
            results << { subscription => player[player.keys.first] }
        else
            failures << subscription
        end
    end
end
```